# Yes/No/Yes to All/No to All message box asp.net

Tags: asp.net, messagebox, confirmation

I want to show a confirmation box include 4 options: Yes/No/Yes to All/No to All after user click a button in my aspx page. I have seen a lot of sample but it only contain Yes/No option. Please show me the way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no native javascript function for that (I guess you saw samples that are using `confirm` function).

Give a try to a javascript library, that create pseudo dialog.

One of the most used is [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com). Especially, look at [the `Dialog confirmation` sample](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation), and you'll ends with something like:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
          // Handler for Yes
        },
        "No": function() {
          // Handler for No
        },
        "Yes to all": function() {
          // Handler for Yes to all
        },
        "No to all": function() {
          // Handler for no to all
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I got error WebDev.WebServer40.exe has stopped working using this method. Do you have any ideal about that?

Comment: The above code is pure javascript. You error is a crash of the web server. You probably have something wrong with your code, but I think it's out of scope of this question.